# How to not owerwrite the parameter with constructor which I got?

Tags: java, constructor

I have this contructor:

```
    private static int list [] = new int[0];
    public IntList (String[] elems){
        this.list = new int[elems.length];
        int j=0;
        for(String i : elems){
            this.list[j] = Integer.parseInt(i);
            ++j;
        }
    }
```

And if I define a new `IntList` than I can't see the original one, the `args`.

```
public static void myTest(IntList args){
  String[] tmpIntList = {"21","22","23","24"};
  IntList newIntListForTest = new IntList(tmpIntList);
  /* for example, if I called myTest with {"1","2","3"},
      and if I print args here then I see only  21,22,23,24*/
}
```

How can I do it to see both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `list` member is `static`, meaning it belongs to the class, not a specific instance. In other words, all the instances of `IntList` share the same `list`, so whenever you create a new instance and overwrite `list`, it's overriden "for all the `IntList`s".

To make a long story short - remove the `static` modified, and you should be fine:

```
private int[] list = new int[0];
```